# Android library - compile two versions of the same library

Tags: android, gradle

I have a library which needs to be a bit different in its debug and release form. I've used buildTypes but I need the resulting jar to be qualified depending on the build type, and then uploaded to an artifactory, and this is really hard to do with just buildTypes.

So I thought about creating a project with two subprojects, one would compile my "debug" library, and the other would compile the "release" one.

The thing is -- essentially they share the same code base. So for the release one, I just create a subdirectory for the release subproject, and assemble normally. But from the debug subdirectory, I need to tell gradle to compile against the release folder (plus exclude some folders and other different stuff from release). So basically I have this structure

```
library
  |
  |--release/src/main/...
  |
  |--debug
```

And I need debug to be compiled against `release` subfolder. I tried `sourceSets` but then only the source files (not the layouts or any other stuff) work.

Is this even possible?

Comment: I answer a similar question time ago, check this link an tell me if it works for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36160135/create-multiple-apk-files-with-one-project-build-in-android-studio/36160356

Comment: @MiguelBenitez thanks, I know about flavors but the problem here is the artifactory stuff, since I need my resulting libraries deployed in different artifactIds